# How do I get bazel to use a specifc VC++ toolset?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, bazel

I have a C++ project which uses Bazel as the build tool, and I am primarily developing on windows.

The latest visual studio toolset (VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest) no longer compiles my C++ code correctly (causes an internal compiler error) in the meantime I would like to continue using the previous toolset (VC++ 2017 version 15.8 v14.15 toolset). I am unsure of how to tell bazel which toolset it should use.

To be more specific. My `BAZEL_VC` variable is set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC`. There are three folders in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC`, one of which is the latest version, two of which are previous versions. I would like to tell Bazel to use one of the previous version folders somehow.

I also can't seem to revert entirely back to the previous toolset. Nor can I remove the latest toolset while still having the older one function. Since windows views this as a responsibility of the build system, I turn to bazel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the future and Bazel has fixed this issue and documented it better. [See here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.1.0/windows.html#build-c-with-msvc).

```
set BAZEL_VC=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC
set BAZEL_VC_FULL_VERSION=14.16.27023
```